# ASP.NET Core usermanger is not saving user roles to AspNetUserRoles table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, usermanager

This is my code - `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<AuthDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

`DatabaseContext.cs`:

```
public class AuthDBContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public AuthDBContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {  }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfig());           
    }
}
```

`UserEntity.cs`:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; } 
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

When debugging, both user and roles objects are passed with data via `await userManager.AddToRolesAsync()`, however when I check database, `userRoles` are not there.

I also tried calling `await context.SaveChanges()` and still no data appears in the database.

`UserService.cs`:

```
public async Task AddRoles(UserDto userDto)
{
    var roles = new List<string>();

    if (userDto.Roles == null)
    {
        roles.Add("User");   //Set Default Role if Null
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var role in userDto.Roles)
        {
            roles.Add(role);
        }
    }

    var user = mapper.Map<User>(userDto);
    await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, roles);
}
```

NB. I have already added `Roles` to `aspnetroles` table like so

[image: List of Role on the Database]

Comment: Show the user object in your debugger variables view + what `AddToRolesAsync` returns?

Comment: I don't find any error in your code, I speculate when you map userDto to user, It loss some field, Then AddToRolesAsync() can't insert data into connect table. you can try to use `var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userDto.userId);` to get the user and try again.

Comment: Most likely your var user is not populating correctly. Put a break point on that line, step over, and update the question with the values of user. I suspect the id isn't mapping correctly and the user manager can't map the roles.